# Switch between Local/Remote Hadoop Config

Tags: hadoop

Is there an easy way to switch between running Hadoop jobs locally and running them on a remote cluster?  I would prefer to do all development locally and run via the command line, changing a parameter or environment variable to switch between running locally or on the remote cluster.

For context, I have a Linux virtual machine with Hadoop installed.  I'm fairly new to Hadoop, but can run local jobs there.

Related question: what good documentation is available for Hadoop configuration?

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you can study the WordCount of hadoop, before run your program, you can set some parameter to complement your job.

As follows, in main() method of WordCount, you can set this parameter to finish it(this sentence added by myself). Please see the picture. Gook Luck!

[image]

Comment: Which configuration keys (in addition to "fs.default.name") must be set in order to switch between a local and remote job?

Comment: This key is enough. Because when job run, it will check this key to decide which FileSystem(local, HDFS, or others) to use. And you can print this key to check wether the set is right.